# How can I free up space from an older Ubuntu partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, gnome, delete

Straight to the point, I have created partitions to install Ubuntu GNOME and its swap, and they in total make up 18 gigabytes. How can I uninstall/delete/remove the OS and still keep the space? And also still be able to install another Ubuntu version?  I dont want to use the "Delete Other Version and Install" method from the LiveUSB installation so if anyone could help, I'd be glad. Thanks.

Edit: I'm not a very good Linux user or tech in general, so I also don't know if my question has answers as I've checked the ones recommended to me when I typed in the title and they mostly did not help me.

Comment: The same way you create partitions you can delete them. OSes don't need to be unuinstalled. However, a dualboot with Windows in a Legacy (BIOS/MBR) installation requires fixing (reinstalling) the Windows bootloader. 18GB total for Ubuntu may not be enough, depending on the software you want to use.

Comment: I won't be downloading anything I suppose other than Steam, and 2 games in it but I was thinking you could install those games in other hard drives like in Mac and PC. Am I wrong? Also you said the way we can create partitions we can also delete them, can I overwrite the Ubuntu OS over the   one thats already installed? Or if we delete them the partition wont be gone, only what is inside it?

Comment: Yes, Steam downloads can be set to other locations. And yes, you need to learn about partitions before trying to install operating systems.

Comment: I sensed a kind of sarcastic tone in your sentence so I'd like to clarify I did not mean to sound rude I just wanted help. ^.^ I do know how to install operating systems but maybe not like any other guy in this forum, I'm pretty new to Linux and just wanted to install Ubuntu. :c Thanks for your help regarding my problem, appreciated. :)

Comment: What you need to know about partitions is actually OS agnostic (partitions don't care about OSes). Different tools can be used, same end result. The partitions specifically required for Ubuntu are already there according to your question. The rest including questions/doubts expressed in comments make no sense. Even a regular Windows user with a basic understanding about partitions and knowing nothing about Linux, is able to identify those "foreign" (to Windows) partitions, remove, create and format a new one (or more) using basic Windows tools.

Comment: You can manage partitions as you want. Create, format, delete anytime you want. And you can reuse any of the partitions you already created for future installations simply by choosing "Something else...", select and tick format if applicable , when installing other Ubuntu or derivatives you may want to try.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Will try! By the way, I am struggling with the help I am given mostly cause of the poor english that I have. even though I look as if I can write proper english I cant understand most detailed text. Also I asked the question because in GNOME there was a delete option to wipe out the partition but in normal Ubuntu from the site (version 16.04) does not have that and has only the "retry" button. that was why I was wondering ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Freeing up space from an older Ubuntu Partition**

There are two ways to free space on a partition.  You can either delete unwanted files and directories individually or in groups, or you can reformat the partition in one swoop.

**Uninstall OS Keep the space**

You don't Uninstall an OS.  You can clean partition where the OS is installed by reformatting the partition.  The OS installs also have options to reformat the partition where you it's being installed.  So using that option will perform both the format as well as a clean install of the OS.

When you remove files from a partition or reformat the partition, you retain the space of the partition.  If you have a 10G partition and are using 5 Gigs of it, you'll have 5 Gigs left on that partiton.  If you delete 3 Gigs of files and folders, you'll then have 8 gigs of space on it.  Deleting all the files and folders on the partition will bring you back to 10 Gigs.  Formatting the partition will give you back the 10 Gigs in one swoop.

**Ubuntu Install Process**

When you are running the LiveUSB to install Ubuntu, you'll have the option to `Erase and use the whole Drive`, `Install alongside` the detected OS already install, or `Something Else`.  If you choose the Something Else option, it will prompt you for your choice for which partition(s) will be used.

**Location of Steam Files**

In response to your comments about using other drives for your Steam Games, the same is with Ubuntu as you indicated for the Mac and PC.  The feature is the same because it's a feature of Steam's settings.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer as I think they are the most useful ones yet. One more question though, hope you don't mind: I had made two partitions, one 10 gig and the other 8 and I used them for the OS and swap. 10g was OS and 8g was swap and I wanted to  make them a file that windows can recognize so I can combine it with the hard disk that I shrunk them from as I researched that it is possible. How can I do so? Thanks so much!

Comment: @Klaus Thanks for the compliment of the merit of my answer.  If your question is about how to delete a partition, you can do this by running `gparted` or `gnome-disk--utility`.  You won't be able to delete a partition that is mounted.  Modifying the partitions is best done from the Live USB.

Comment: Thanks for advice. I will try them out but unfortunately everything seems off for me all the time, cause whenever I try to install and use ubuntu it just crashes and never works again. I've installed it more than 3 times now and all of them either wont boot up after shutdown or some weird part of the operating system wont launch so when I restart to fix it it doesn't boot up, vice versa. Thanks for your help though, I appreciate it.

Comment: @Klaus Reinstalling should be a last alternative.  It's always best to try to fix a problem rather than starting over.  As you see from experience, starting over can be a cycle that will only be broken by sticking with an installation, and diagnosing how to fix what's broken.  I find all the issues to turn out to be something simple.  Sometimes the simplest is harder for an individual to see.  If you post the issue, in a question specific to that issue, you'll have hundreds of minds that will look at it and point out something, as I mentioned, that is always simple.

Comment: Thanks, I posted everything that has happpened to me as a question on how to fix it but I have limited time so I'm going to try out other Linux distros. Any distros you know that are more stable and user friendly?

Comment: Actually I believe Ubuntu best fits the description of your question.  It also appears to be the most popular and supported.  It might appear that way because I use it so much.  Ubuntu is the third distro that I went to.  I switched to Ubuntu 8 years ago for the very reason that described.